# How to sync my pictures from FlashAir to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

based on this answer: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/92941/71846

I'm trying to set up my new Toshiba FlashAir to sync with my Google Drive account.

The instructions are here: http://www.fixstars.com/en/news/?p=451

However, I'm having trouble with part 1 of the second step (I suspect the steps are actually out of date).

[image: screenshot of postman request]

I've left out the information in the form-data because my Google API Key is there.

From the instructions, it mentions: "NOTE: Google tells you to use “https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive” for scope, but this will return a “Invalid_scope: Not authorized to request the scope”. Using /feeds/ instead will grant us the Google Drive authorization we need."

So I also tried using “https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive” for scope but I'm getting the same "invalid request" back in the JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that in your question, there might be a problem at the process for retrieving refresh token. So how about using Drive API? The following flow is from part 1 to part 3 of the sample for Google Drive of `https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/92941/71846` in your question. This flow retrieves the refresh token for using Drive API.

### Flow :

1. On your browser.

   1. Create new project at https://console.developers.google.com/
   2. At "Library" of `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com/?project=### project ID ###`, enable Drive API.
   3. Go to "Credential" of `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=### project ID ###`.
   4. Create Credential

      1. Select "Help me choose"
      2. At "Which API are you using?", select "Drive API".
      3. At "Where will you be calling the API from?", select "Other UI (e.g. Windows, CLI tool)".
      4. At "What data will you be accessing?", select "User data".
      5. Click "What credentials do I need?"
      6. At "Name of Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID", Input name.
      7. Click "Create Client ID".
      8. Click "Done." By this, back to Credentials screen.
      9. Click the created credentials.

         - Copy "Client ID" and "Client secret"
   5. Please input your clientId and access `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=### clientId ###&response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

      - By authorizing, the code is retrieved.
      - Copy "code".
2. On your terminal.

   1. Retrieve refresh token using curl command. Please input your clientId, client secret and retrieved code.

      - `curl -X POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "client_id=### clientId ###" -d "client_secret=### client secret ###" -d "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "code=### code ###"`

### Note :

- If you have already enabled Drive API and retrieved client ID and client secret, you can start from 5. If that didn't work, please start from 1.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: No I think you're answering my question correctly but I'm still getting: `{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Could not determine client ID from request."
}`    I've tried a few times but I keep getting the same response. Note that my client id ends with "fd.apps.googleusercontent.com"

Comment: something was indeed wrong with my request. I had to reformat it a few times to get it working. Not sure what the problem was exactly but I got the access token now.

Comment: So I'm looking at this more closely and I think you've skipped past my issue. Please look at step 2 here: ` http://www.fixstars.com/en/news/?p=451` What I need is to get the device code. On *that* step I'm getting the invalid request as a response.

Comment: @Ramy I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I'm not sure I can correctly understand your current situation. If I misunderstand your situation, please tell me. You said that you could retrieve the access token.(refresh token?) In that case, the device code had already been retrieved. Because the access token and refresh token are retrieved using the code.

Comment: no need to apologize at all. I will take another look and see if maybe this is working. I'm obviously very new to google-api's so thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Ramy Thank you for your concern. After the refresh token and access token were retrieved, the device code is not required. You can use APIs using the tokens. My answer is the flow for retrieving the tokens. So you can go to step 4 of your URL using the tokens.

Comment: @Ramy I noticed the accept. Can I think that your problem was solved? If it's so, I'm glad.